# Different encoding using "android.util.Base64" and "org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;"

Tags: android, encoding, base64

I am programming an authentication service in Android and this one includes a server part written in java.
I do the same operations in both parts executing these two pieces of codes in Android and Server:

ANDROID:

```
String genChallengeResponse(String challenge, String message) {
  String Hmac_ALG = "HmacSHA256";
  SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(challenge.getBytes(), Hmac_ALG);
  Mac m = Mac.getInstance(Hmac_ALG);
  m.init(key);
  m.update(password.getBytes());
  byte[] mac = m.doFinal();
  return new String(Base64.encode(mac, Base64.DEFAULT));
}
```

SERVER:

```
String genChallengeResponse(String challenge, String message) {
  String Hmac_ALG = "HmacSHA256";
  SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(challenge.getBytes(), Hmac_ALG);
  Mac m = Mac.getInstance(Hmac_ALG);
  m.init(key);
  m.update(password.getBytes());
  byte[] mac = m.doFinal();
  return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(mac));
}
```

Starting from the same challenge and message these are the results:

```
Android: n2EaLpQr0uKgkZKhCQzwuIFeeLjzZKerZcETVNcfla4=
Server:  n2EaLpQr0uKgkZKhCQzwuD9eeLjzZKerZcETVNcfla4=
                              ^^
```

These are different just for TWO CHARACTERS.
The problem is that this strange behaviour does not appear in every pair of String passed to the functions...

I tried to use the UTF-8 in each system, but nothing changes...
Do someone knows what is the problem? If this is a known problem...

(is important to say that the problem is the same using Android 2.2 or also 4.0, then the problem is not the operating system, I think).

Answer (score 2):

Can't comment yet therefore as answer:

I found out a few weeks ago that Android's Base64 uses different settings for the Linefeeds (check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html )

I think in my case it was NO_WRAP missing.Perhaps one of the other options (NO_PADDING or URL-Safe, does the tested password contain + or - ?) could change your results...

Comment: Already tried all the variants: CRLF, NO_CLOSE, NO_PADDING, NO_WRAP, URL_SAFE... nothing...
Another string with problems is n2EaLpQr0uKgkZKhCQzwuIFeeLjzZKerZcETVNcfla4=  <-->  n2EaLpQr0uKgkZKhCQzwuD9eeLjzZKerZcETVNcfla4=

Then the problem is not the precence of + or - ...
Thanks however

Comment: Strings equal before Base64 ?

Comment: Yes... I checked it.
I think that if these were not equals the generated string would be totally different (because of the SHA256 algorithm).

Comment: Using NO_WRAP did it for me!